# How do I arrange fitted GAM plots and include summary information on the plots in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, gam, mgcv

I have two fitted GAM models that represent two sites with each model having two independent variables. I would like to arrange the resulting four GAM plots into a single, 2 column 2 row figure (see below example). The top row would represent the model results for one site, and the bottom row represents the model results for the second site. All y-axes have the same variable, so I would like for there to be only one y-axis title along the left column while preserving the two independent x-axis titles. Once these GAM plots are arranged, I would like to include the Adj. R2 value and site name with the plots.

```
library(mgcv)

df1 <- data.frame(x1 = rnorm(50), x2 = rnorm(50), y1 = rnorm(50))
df2 <- data.frame(x1 = rnorm(50), x2 = rnorm(50), y2 = rnorm(50))

df1$Site <- "Site1"
df2$Site <- "Site2"

m1 <- gam(y1 ~ s(x1) + s(x2), data = df1)
m2 <- gam(y2 ~ s(x1) + s(x2), data = df2)

p1 <- plot(m1)
p2 <- plot(m2)

summary(m1) # This is where the Adj. R2 value comes from for m1
summary(m2) # This is where the Adj. R2 value comes from for m2
```

I have tried using `p1/p2 + plot_layout(ncol = 2, heights = c(1,1))` but got `Error in p1/p2 : non-numeric argument to binary operator` and I have also tried using `grid.arrange(p1,p2, ncol = 2)` but got the error `Error in gList(list(list(x = c(-2.390381407938, -2.3411392450022, -2.29189708206641,  : 
  only 'grobs' allowed in "gList"`

Ultimately I would like a figure that looks like this:
[image]

Comment: These are base graphics plots. Functions from the `patchwork` package (`p1/p2`, etc.) or `gridExtra` package (e.g., `grid.arrange`) only work with grid graphics (the graphics engine that produces ggplot and lattice plots). To arrange base graphics plots, see the `layout` function or you can also create layouts with `par(mfrow=c(2,2))` for a 2x2 layout. Or you can recreate the plots using `ggplot2` and lay them out using `patchwork`.

Comment: To add text to a base graphics plot, such as the model summary info, see the `text` function.

Comment: @eipi10 if I add `p1 <- plot(m1, shade = TRUE, text(x = -1, y = 1.25, labels = "R2 = 0.21"))` I get the error `Error in if (partial.resids) { : argument is of length zero`. Also I don't see how I could add text to the second plot in `p1` this way.

Comment: @ eipi10 Using `ggplot2` to recreate these plots would be ideal, however, it is unclear how that would be done.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest the library [`visreg`](https://pbreheny.github.io/visreg/) which can produce `ggplot` by `mgcv` gam object:

```
library(mgcv)
library(visreg)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(101)
df1 <- data.frame(x1 = rnorm(50), x2 = rnorm(50), y1 = rnorm(50))
df2 <- data.frame(x1 = rnorm(50), x2 = rnorm(50), y2 = rnorm(50))

df1$Site <- "Site1"
df2$Site <- "Site2"

m1 <- gam(y1 ~ s(x1) + s(x2), data = df1)
m2 <- gam(y2 ~ s(x1) + s(x2), data = df2)


# Setting some ggplot style here
ggstyle <- theme_classic()+
              theme(axis.text = element_text(color = "black"))

# Covariates of model m1
p1 <- visreg(m1, "x1", gg = TRUE, plot = TRUE) +
          ggstyle +
          labs(title = "Model 1") 

p2 <- visreg(m1, "x2", gg = TRUE, plot = TRUE)+
          ggstyle

# Covariates of model m2
p3 <- visreg(m2, "x1", gg = TRUE, plot = TRUE)+
          ggstyle +
          labs(title = "Model 2") 

p4 <- visreg(m2, "x2", gg = TRUE, plot = TRUE)+
          ggstyle 


    # Aggregate plots
grid.arrange(arrangeGrob(p1, p2, p3, p4, ncol = 2,
             left = textGrob("Global Y-axis Label", rot = 90, vjust = 1)))
```

### Result:

[image]

---

In addition, if you prefer, can generate a `visreg` object for the covariate `x1`, with both data and fits:

```
p1 <- visreg(m1, "x1", gg = TRUE, plot = FALSE)
```

After you can easly use `ggplot`:

```
ggplot()+
  geom_point(data = p1$res, aes(x1, visregRes), shape = 21, size = 3, fill = "#2ca25f")+
  geom_line(data = p1$fit, aes(x1, visregFit))+
  geom_line(data = p1$fit, aes(x1, visregLwr), linetype = 3)+
  geom_line(data = p1$fit, aes(x1, visregUpr), linetype = 3)+
  theme_classic()
```

[image]